# How to keep group on same page, have other text go around it?

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs, article, wrap

I have an article with images which have paragraphs that go with them. I'd like to keep the images and their paragraphs on the same page no matter what, and have other text go around them. I've tried `wrapfigure`, but that puts text on the side. I want other paragraphs to be split up to keep these images and their text on the same page.

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.75\columnwidth]{image.png}\\
\end{center}
{\footnotesize\textbf{Figure X.} Description.\par}
```

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not very clear what you want. Do you mean an image (horizontally) in the centre of the page, and text flowing on the left and on the right of the image?

Comment: No, I have the group of an image and a paragraph that need to stay together. I want no other text on the side of this group, but text above and below it if that needs to happen. Also I should note, my article is in 2 columns, and I don't want to break those columns.

Comment: Did you try putting image and paragraph together in a minipage? Still not very clear, though.

Comment: I think that adding a picture would help to clarify your question.  Even a photo of a hand-made drawing would be OK.

Comment: Did you consider using a floating environment, say, a figure environment?  Something like

Comment: Boxes, minipages, tables --- there are many ways (probably) to do this. But your description is not clear enough.